# I have a bug in my program that I cannot figure out

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, debugging

So, I just recently started coding and decided to make a rock paper scissors game; However, my program has a bug where if the user enters "rock" the correct code block doesn't run. Instead it runs an else statement that's only meant to run when the user enters, "no". I tried using a while loop instead of just if else statements but it didn't make a difference.

```
import random

q_1 = str(input("Hello, want to play Rock Paper Scissors?:"))

print()
# ^^adds an indent
rpc_list = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]

comp = random.choice(rpc_list)
# ^^randomly selects r, p, or s

user = str(input("Great, select Rock Paper or Scissors:"))
if q_1 != "yes":
    if q_1 == comp:
        print("Oh No, a Tie!")
    elif q_1 == "rock":
        if comp == "paper":
            print("I Win!")
        else:
            print("You Win!")
    elif q_1 == "paper":
        if comp == "rock":
            print("You Win!")
        else:
            print("I Win!")
    else:
        if comp == "rock":
            print("I Win!")
        else:
            print("You Win!")
else:
    print("Ok :(")
```

Comment: The [tag:pygame] tag is intended to be used for questions related to the [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/news) library.

Comment: To debug this, you printed out the values of `q_1` and `user`, yes? Were the values what you expected?

Comment: Your guess is stored in `user`, not `q_1`. When you look at `elif q_1 == “rock”`, you’re checking the wrong variable.

Comment: Also your game only starts if they didn't say 'yes'..

Comment: the issue is here `q_1 != "yes"` so if someone says "yes" to the first question that will evaluate as `False` You can put a `print(q_1 != "yes")` before `if q_1 != "yes":` statement to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code.

First of all your code only plays the game if the user *doesn't* enter "yes". You need to change `if q_1 != "yes":` to `if q_1 == "yes":`.

Secondly, your code asks the user to choose rock, paper or scissors regardless of whether they have said they want to play or not. Fix this by moving `user = str(input("Great, select Rock Paper or Scissors:"))` to under the `if q_1 == "yes":` if statement.

Thirdly, your code uses `q1` instead of `user` as it should.

Here is how your code should look:

```
import random

q_1 = str(input("Hello, want to play Rock Paper Scissors?:"))

print()
# ^^adds an indent
rpc_list = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]

comp = random.choice(rpc_list)
# ^^randomly selects r, p, or s

if q_1 == "yes":
    user = str(input("Great, select Rock Paper or Scissors:"))
    if user == comp:
        print("Oh No, a Tie!")
    elif user == "rock":
        if comp == "paper":
            print("I Win!")
        else:
            print("You Win!")
    elif user == "paper":
        if comp == "rock":
            print("You Win!")
        else:
            print("I Win!")
    else:
        if comp == "rock":
            print("I Win!")
        else:
            print("You Win!")
    print("I played:",comp)
else:
    print("Ok :(")
```